# Interpretation of more than one cross price elasticity of demand

Tags: demand-system-estimation, cross-price-elasticity

I am writing an empirical paper and use cross sectional data to estimate elasticities using an "almost ideal demand system" by Deaton and Muellbauer (1980) using Stata.

My question concerns the interpretation of cross price elasticities. In my understanding I can only interpret the cross price elasticity of demand of good i with respect to a price increase of good j. What if the demand system also contains good k, l and so on? Or in other words, are cross price elasticities still interpretable if I'd like to include cross price effects of more than one good?

If the context helps: I am looking into the effects of a carbon tax on meat and dairy goods. So in my first scenario I simply use own-price elasticities of the taxed good and multiply by the percentage price increase through the tax. This all works fine!

In my second scenario, instead of introducing a CO2 tax on meat and dairy goods, I would like to look into how demand for meat and dairy goods changes if the value added tax for plant based foods were abandoned, or in other words how relative price changes would affect the demand. That is I need to calculate how say the demand for beef changes if all plant based products become cheaper by a certain percentage. Is that possible?

Thanks for any response!

Best,
Julian

Comment: Hello Julian, I have just seen your question. It really resembles my long-time curiosity: elasticity of substitution in case of multiple goods: [My question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/54118/relation-between-complements-and-substitutes-for-multiple-goods). I think that your question would be solved immediately when knowing what happens with elasticity of substitution since behavior of cross price elasticity might be deduced from it. Regarding your question, I think cross price elasticity is still valid, since we can fix other variables...